# getAriaValueText of the Slider from material ui has no effect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

https://codesandbox.io/s/qnc7v?file=/demo.js

The above example is taken directly from the material ui website.

```
      <Slider
        defaultValue={80}
   //     getAriaValueText={valuetext}
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always"
        step={10}
        marks={marks}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
      />
```

if you comment out the argument like I did, it changes nothing.

Comment: Did you try it on a screen reader? That's the main thing affected by aria attributes.

Comment: `getAriaValueText` adds a `aria-valuetext` attribute to the generated slider markup and shows the updated value of the slider for assistive technologies. When you commented out this line (`getAriaValueText={valuetext}`), the generated markup didn't have the attribute `aria-valuetext`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <Slider
    defaultValue={80}
    getAriaValueText={(e) => console.log(e)}
    aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always"
    step={10}
    marks={marks}
    valueLabelDisplay="on"
  />
```